# Surprising behavior of transparent signature ascription

Tags: module, sml, signature

I want to define my own abstract type `'a foo`, that, like `'a ref`, is an `eqtype` even if `'a` isn't. For example:

```
lolcathost% poly
Poly/ML 5.5.2 Release
> signature FOO =
# sig
#   eqtype 'a foo
#   val bar : real foo
#   val qux : real foo
# end;
signature FOO = sig val bar : real foo type 'a foo val qux : real foo end
> structure Foo : FOO =
# struct
#   datatype 'a wat = Wat of 'a
#   type 'a foo = 'a wat ref
#   val bar = ref (Wat 0.0)
#   val qux = ref (Wat 0.0)
# end;
structure Foo : FOO
> Foo.bar = Foo.qux;
val it = false: bool
```

So far, so good! Now:

```
> !Foo.bar;
val it = Wat 0.0: real wat
> !Foo.qux;
val it = Wat 0.0: real wat
```

Wait. Isn't `wat` supposed to be hidden? Why am I seeing values of type `real wat`?

Comment: Maybe a `ref` type can't be completely opaque since the compiler needs to know how much memory to allocate and how to interpret the bit pattern that is there. What you show sort of reminds me of how in C you can't dereference a void pointer without casting it to a specific type. I don't know if it is more weird or less weird than what you have but in SML/NJ when I enter your definitions and type `!Foo.bar` I get `val it = Wat 0.0 : real ?.Foo.wat`

Comment: @JohnColeman: I don't even want external code to be aware that `foo`s are internally reference cells. I want an abstract type constructor, that *happens* to share with `ref`s the property that it yields `eqtype`s, even when its type arguments themselves aren't.

Comment: Of course, for `!x` to typecheck, `x` has to be of type `a foo` for some type `a`. Since I don't want outside code to know that `'a foo` is internally `'a wat ref`, this means that `!Foo.bar` and `!Foo.qux` should not typecheck in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't `wat` supposed to be hidden?

It's "hidden" in the sense that code cannot refer to it; but since you as a human are aware of it, there's no reason for the REPL to be evasive about it.

> Why am I seeing values of type `real wat`?

Why not? The identifier `wat` is not in scope, but the type-name still exists. There's no reason there can't be values of types that involve it.

(The same thing is possible even without signatures; something like

```
local
   datatype 'a wat = Wat of 'a
in
   val it = Wat 0.0
end
```

is perfectly valid, and has a similar effect.)

> Since I don't want outside code to know that `'a foo` is internally `'a wat ref`, this means that `!Foo.bar` and `!Foo.qux` should not typecheck in the first place.

If you don't want outside code to know that `'a foo` is internally `'a wat ref`, then you shouldn't use transparent ascription; the whole point of transparent ascription is that outside code still knows what the type is even if the signature doesn't specify it (as opposed to opaque ascription, where outside code really only has what's specified in the signature).

> I want to define my own abstract type `'a foo`, that, like `'a ref`, is an `eqtype` even if `'a` isn't.

Unfortunately, this is not possible. *The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)* (which defines Standard ML '97, for the most part) lays out the exact set of equality types in §4.4 "Types and Type Functions", on page 17. A constructed type admits equality only if (1) its type name and all of its type arguments admit equality or (2) its type name is the one denoted by `ref`. In your case, since `'a` obviously isn't an equality type, and `foo` is not `ref`, `'a foo` doesn't admit equality.

(Note: I should mention that the *Definition* is a little bit wrong here, in that *The Standard ML Basis Library* specifies a few additional type names that have the same special property as `ref`, and compilers implement these as well. But this extension just adds more hardcoding; it doesn't add any way for programmers to create additional such type names.)